# Udemy-dl is not recognised inspite of installing it

Tags: video

> C:\Users\User>pip install udemy-dl
>
> Requirement already satisfied: udemy-dl in
>   c:\python27\lib\site-packages
>
> Requirement already satisfied: requests in
>   c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from udemy-dl)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: unicode-slugify in
>   c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from udemy-dl)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: colorlog in
>   c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from udemy-dl)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: future in c:\python27\lib\site-packages
>   (from udemy-dl)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.23,>=1.21.1 in
>   c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from requests->udemy-dl)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.7,>=2.5 in
>   c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from requests->udemy-dl)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in
>   c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from requests->udemy-dl)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in
>   c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from requests->udemy-dl)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\python27\lib\site-packages
>   (from unicode-slugify->udemy-dl)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: unidecode in
>   c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from unicode-slugify->udemy-dl)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: colorama; sys_platform == "win32" in
>   c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from colorlog->udemy-dl)
>
> C:\Users\User>udemy-dl 'udemy-dl' is not recognized as an internal or
>   external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, read the [ask] page and update your question.

Answer (score 2):

udemy-dl works as a module (udemy_dl). To invoke it, you need to call as follows:

```
python -m udemy_dl [URL of the course you are trying to download]
```

It would then ask you to input your Username & Password.

Let us know if that worked.

Comment: I needed to run pip3 install udemy-dl (pip3 not pip) and this command with -m works for me

Answer (score 1):

udemy-dl is possibly not installed as executable; but it is installed as python module. Find out the module's name.
Open a python interpreter in Windows command prompt:

```
C:\Users\User>python
```

In python interpreter prompt, type following command to list modules:

```
>>> help('modules')
```

Look for udemy module. It might be named as `udemy_dl` or similar.

Exit the python interpreter prompt:

```
exit()
```

Run udemy downloader as python module (replace `udemy_dl` with the module name looked earlier):

```
python -m udemy_dl --help
```